# Java write ArrayList of Objects in a File

Tags: java, string, file, io, printwriter

i want to write all Password Objects, which are stored in PasswordDatabase in a file. But in this file a are many cryptic signs. I want my Arraylist print like this in the file:    MyPC superpassword and so on.

```
public class PasswordDatabase {

ArrayList<Password> password = new ArrayList<Password>();

public void getAllPasswords() {

    for (Password p : password) {
        System.out.println(p.getPassword() + " " + p.getLocation());
    }
 }
}


public class Password implements Serializable  {

String Password;
String Location;

public Password(String Password, String Location) {
    this.Password = Password;
    this.Location = Location;
 }
}


class Test {
 PasswordDataBase db = new PasswordDatabase

public void writeInFile() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new 
        FileOutputStream((System.getProperty("user.home")+"/test.txt"));
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
        oos.writeObject(db.getallPasswords()); 
        oos.close(); 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: What made you think the `ObjectOutputStream` was the right choice for this task?

Comment: Probably no right choice beause of the Arraylist.

Comment: But what should i use instead of ObjectOutputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ObjectOutputStream` is only meant to be use if you want a serialization format that is easy to read by Java, and not necessarily easy to read by humans.

If you want a particular format, you would probably benefit from using a `PrintStream` instead.

Comment: I have tried this:   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/test.txt"));
   
     for(Passwort p:db.getAllPasswords()) {
      pw.println((db.getAllPasswords()));
     }
    p.flush();
    p.close(); But there also cryptic signs in the file

Comment: What if you print one line at a time rather than the whole list at once?

Comment: Very nice now it works: for(Password pa:db.getAllPasswords()) {
      p.println((pa.getLocation()+" " +pa.getPassword()));
     } Should i change the title of my question because  it has nothing to do with ObjectOutputStream?